# How to use a for loop with promise all?

Tags: javascript

how do I change the urls in the code below with a for loop? In other words, instead of fetching the URLs below, how do I fetch a range of IP addresses "192.168.1.1-192.168.1.255?

```
    let urls = [
      'https://url1',
      'https://url2',
      'https://url3',
    ];
    let requests = urls.map(url => fetch(url));
    Promise.all(requests)
      .then(responses => responses.forEach(
        response => console.log(`${response.url}: ${response.status}`)
      ));
```

Thanks for the assistance

Comment: Your question is how to create a range? Then that `fetch` and `promise.all` part is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

As you have working code when the input is a list or URLs, just make a list of URLs according to the pattern:

```
urls = list(f"https://192.168.1.{i}" for i in range(1, 255))
```